# Query string concatenation with a string variable

Tags: asp.net

I have a problem in this query,
country is a variable.
Error: country is invalid column name..

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [news_id], [news_title] from [upload_news] WHERE [city]="+ country;
```

Comment: What is the value of the variable 'country' ?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
"SELECT [news_id], [news_title] from [upload_news] WHERE [city]='"+ country +"'";
```

However as indicated the proper way to do add a condition to your select statement is using a variable:

```
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [news_id], [news_title] from [upload_news] WHERE [city]=@param"
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("param", country);
```

PS: your first attempt did not work because you actual SQL being executed would like:

```
SELECT [news_id], [news_title] from [upload_news] WHERE [city] = USA
```

vs

```
SELECT [news_id], [news_title] from [upload_news] WHERE [city] = 'USA'
```

Comment: Do not teach to use string concatenation to build query commands